# Consequences for contractor of bypassing recruitment agency

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, contracting, legal

I have given a recruitment agency in the UK permission to represent me with a previous employer of mine, a company which I worked for and left 2 years ago.

The recruitment agency introduced me to the company and they saw on my CV that I had already worked for them, and decided to contact me directly as they had my details on file.

This company I worked for ended up making an offer and I accepted it, knowing we were bypassing the recruitment agency because I was already known to the them (the company).

The recruitment agency is threatening to take legal action against the company and advising me that I shouldn't accept the role as to avoid getting involved in this legal mess. I believe they might be trying to scare me and put pressure on me to persuade the company use the recruiters and pay the feeds. The company, however, is relaxed and said the situation is not unheard of, and there is nothing for me to worry about.

My question is - what I am liable for by accepting this role directly from the company, when I have given the recruitment agency the right to represent me with them (albeit informally and only be email)?

Am I likely to find myself in legal trouble for simply accepting the role?

Not sure how much difference it makes, but I have not worked with the recruitment agency before and it was them who approached me. Also, I'm a contractor, operating through my limited company.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're asking legal questions which are out of scope for this site. Right now the argument *should be* between the recruiting agency and your former (and possibly future) employer. But you've inserted yourself into it by accepting the offer. It probably would have been better to inform both companies that you could not render a decision until their dispute was settled.

Comment: This question is not asking for legal advice, and the scope is in that which would be expected to know by business managers or HR Types.  This question is on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unlikely to face any real consequences legally.

Most companies include in their contract with outside staffing agencies that the company has no claims about previous or current employees that they present to the company, or candidates that have been presented to them by other means in the last 12 months(this number varies).  Assuming you advised the recruiter of the fact that you had worked for this company previously, then the staffing agency is probably having little or no claim against the company.

However, accepting the position will probably burn the bridge with the staffing agency.  If you are in a market with many agencies, and this agency is not a particularly generous with their remuneration, this is probably not a big deal.  If they are one of the better companies to work with you may want to consider taking some action to keep your relationship with the agency on good terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes perfect sense. However I'm fairly positive the company hiring me doesn't have a contract with the staffing agency as this has been mentioned in some emails. I believe the staffing agency emailed the company speculatively and is trying to bind them to their standard Terms and Conditions.

Comment: @Andre that's a terrible position for the recruiting agency *and* the company. Unfortunately it sounds like the recruiting agency is going to lose this one, and they're probably going to lose any future dealings with this company because of how they handled your situation.

Comment: Thanks @Thebluefish, that's seems reasonable. I would be happy either way but I do know for a fact that I wouldn't get the job through the staffing agency as they were asking a 30% fee which would immediately make me prohibitively expensive for the end client. Thanks everyone for the advice and apologies if the question is off-topic.

Comment: @andre It is not really a contract so much as an agreement that can be enforced.  A contract would imply that there was some service that would be completed.  It is unlikely that the agency provided your information with out some agreement in place.  The agreement would not require the company to accept any candidates or cost the company anything up front, only when they sign a contract to actually fill a position.

Comment: @Chad Understood, what I know is that the company hiring didn't have "terms in place" with the staffing agency, so the company is trying to avoid paying fees because the recruiter sent a full CV without having terms in place to cover themselves. Anyway, I'm more concerned about implications to myself as the candidate. Other than burning a bridge with the staffing agency (which frankly doesn't bother me much) I'm confident I'm not in breach of contract as I simply don't have a contract in place with the staffing agency or anything else that explicitly forbids me from trading with this company.

Comment: Even if you had a non compete since they did not have the terms in place you would not be subject to that.  You could end up in court or depositions but it would be as a witness.  Granted they can sue you too but if they do the company should protect you as part of their protecting themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly speaking, the potential breach of contract is between the recruiting agency and the company you applied for.

> The company, however, is relaxed and said the situation is not unheard of, and there is nothing for me to worry about.

If you are worried about potential ramifications, get this in writing, accept the job, and then let the company deal with it.

Of course, don't expect to get any offerings from the recruiting agency later down the road.